# Can I use a gitlab-ci.yml with a Bitbucket repo to create a pipeline?

Tags: bitbucket, gitlab-ci, bitbucket-pipelines

So we migrated all our Gitlab projects to Bitbucket. We'd like to use the existing gitlab-ci.yml files for Bitbucket pipelines. Could we do that? If yes, could someone please give some steps to carry that out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not, recently I did the same job and I wrote all the pipeline yamls from scratch. They don't behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab supports mirroring repositories between git servers, but it’s only free for public/open source repositories. Otherwise you have to be on a paid plan, regardless if you use gitlab.com or an on-premise installation. Pushing from Gitlab to another server is free, but pulling from elsewhere to Gitlab is a Premium feature. You can read more about this in [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html)

Otherwise, there are open source utilities that will mirror repositories for you but they have to be configured and maintained properly. One such utility is [gitlab-mirror](https://github.com/samrocketman/gitlab-mirrors).